# angular $broadcast event is not firing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send data from parent to child controller but its not firing event from parent controller its been hours i am scratching my head find the problem but i failed so decided to ask help on stackoverflow, Any idea what is wrong in below code ?

ParentCtrl.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
    .controller('ModelerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state','$log', 'toastr', 'FileSaver', 'Blob', '$uibModal', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function($scope, $state, $log, toastr, FileSaver, Blob, $uibModal, $rootScope, $timeout) {

            $scope.deleteXml = function(id, toast) {
                var id = $scope.diagramObj._id;
                $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/modeler/modelerDialog/modelerDialog.html',
                    controller: 'ModelerDialogCtrl'
                });
                $timeout(function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('delete-diagram', {
                        id: id
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

childCtrl.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
  .controller('ModelerDialogCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,$log,diagramService,$rootScope) {

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.$on('delete-diagram',function(e,data){
      console.log('in $on',data);
    });
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `$scope.$parent.$broadcast('delete-diagram', {id: id});` work?

Comment: Hmm, could be a timing issue. Are you attempting to broadcast an event to a modal after you request for it to be opened? If so, I'd hook into the modals `rendered` or `opened` resolves so you can execute code after you know the modal has been rendered. $scope.modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {

});

Comment: @ John F I used your approach it works and i see data in child controller but i also see the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- ModelerDialogCtrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you pass the id when you open the modal such as:

```
$scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'app/modeler/modelerDialog/modelerDialog.html',
  controller: 'ModelerDialogCtrl',
  resolve: {
    item: function() {
      return $scope.diagramObj._id
    }
   }
 });
```

Fetch it in the child component in this way:
angular.module('angularModelerApp')

```
 .controller('ModelerDialogCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,$log,diagramService,$rootScope) {

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.$on('delete-diagram',function(e,data){
      console.log('in $on',data);
    });


    $uibModalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: how i will rendered id in child controller ?

Comment: i could not build the application there is some syntax issue with parent code at line : `return{id:id}`

Comment: Updated again ..Check now

Comment: i got this error when i open modal window `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- ModelerDialogCtrl`

Comment: I added it in the controller to see it better.